# handle click event outside of button

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I am trying to practice c# by reproduce an App that is in the Apple AppStore.

In the app, there is a rectangle with the text: `"Touch me"`. When you touch it, the rectangle repositions itself.

After you do this a few times, the text changes to "Do not Touch me". In that case you have to Touch outside of the rectangle.

It all went well, up to the point where you have to touch outside the rectangle.

Here is my event handler:

```
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (click == 0)
        {
            if (rectangle1.IsMouseOver || textBlock1.IsMouseOver)
            {
               // reposition and stuff
                if (clicks == 10)
                {
                    // Change the value of the variable click to 1 
                    click = 1;
                    textBlock1.Text = "Do Not Click me";
                    Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock1, 200);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (rectangle1.IsMouseOver || textBlock1.IsMouseOver)
            {
                // Game Over
                this.Close();
            } else
            {
                // reposition and stuff

                click = 0;
                textBlock1.Text = "Click me";
                Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock1, 225);
            }
        }
    }
```

The program works perfectly up to the point where you have to click outside the rectangle.

The program closes when you click on the rectangle but when you click outside it, nothing happens.
Is there any event-handler that can do the task i want?

Here is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ClickMe.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="510" Width="525" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Canvas Name="canvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown_1">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Name="rectangle1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="509" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="63"/>
    <Label Name="label1" Content="0" Canvas.Left="57" Canvas.Top="446"/>
    <Label Content="Klicks:" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="446"/>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Canvas.Left="225" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click Me" Canvas.Top="74" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>

</Canvas>
```

Comment: Depends, we'd need to see the xaml. We have no way of knowing what contains this rectangle -- perhaps you can fire a MouseClick event for whatever your container is? If not, create a container that can do so.

Comment: i added the xaml file.
The rectangle does not have a click event as far as i know, this is why i used the Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown event.

Comment: i don't publish it in the app store, i just try to rebuild the app for windows, for my own amusement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need to set the Background of the Canvas, as it only gets mouse input where it has "rendered content". The background could even be transparent:

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Background="Transparent"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown_1">
    ...
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas) is a `UIElement`. This allows the use of the [`PointerPressed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed) event.

```
private void Target_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;

    if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {

        Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Target);
        if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            //do yo thang
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seem like a good plan, but when i try to implement this to my code i get the following error: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

By the way, i try to reproduce the program as a simple windows 7 program (not for a mobile device)

Comment: The error message is quite clear, you need to add a reference to that assembly to your project...

Comment: This may work in a Windows Store App, but I guess not in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead of  `Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown_1` event:

```
protected override OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Changed == MouseButton.Left)
      {
    // Your logic on mouse down will go here
      }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

with this you can click anywhere on the canvas and get the event to fire. I hope this helps..

Comment: Or just set the Canvas' Background.

Comment: This solution only works because you override the mouse event handler in the MainWindow class, and the window has a background by default. Try setting `Background="{x:Null}"`, and it won't work any more. And by the way, if you would override OnMouseLeftButtonDown there would be no need to check e.Changed.